Error: The argument type 'RawKeyEvent' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'KeyEvent' in Pluto Grid Dependency
I'm working on a Flutter application and recently encountered an error that causes the application to stop working. Here are the details
`../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/pluto_grid-7.0.2/lib/src/manager/shortcut/pluto_grid_shortcut.dart:33:39: Error: The
argument type 'RawKeyEvent' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'KeyEvent'.

'RawKeyEvent' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/raw_keyboard.dart'
('../../../Documents/FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/raw_keyboard.dart').
'KeyEvent' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/hardware_keyboard.dart'
('../../../Documents/FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/hardware_keyboard.dart').
if (action.key.accepts(keyEvent.event, state)) {
^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/pluto_grid-7.0.2/lib/src/manager/shortcut/pluto_grid_shortcut.dart:33:46: Error: The
argument type 'RawKeyboard' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'HardwareKeyboard'.
'RawKeyboard' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/raw_keyboard.dart'
('../../../Documents/FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/raw_keyboard.dart').
'HardwareKeyboard' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/hardware_keyboard.dart'
('../../../Documents/FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/hardware_keyboard.dart').
if (action.key.accepts(keyEvent.event, state)) {`

I had tried out:

flutter pub cache clean
flutter pub get

Flutter version :
Flutter 3.22.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 761747bfc5 (9 weeks ago) • 2024-06-05 22:15:13 +0200
Engine • revision edd8546116
Tools • Dart 3.4.3 • DevTools 2.34.3
pluto grid version :
pluto_grid: ^7.0.2
